# If on term-page -> get the current term?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, conditional-tags, breadcrumb

I'm trying to write a kind of "breadcrumb" function in my "functions.php"

I'd like to query if I'm on a term-page and if so I want to print the current term I'm in.

By "term-page" I mean the following. I list all terms of a custom-taxonomy (associated with a custom-post-type) as kind of categories in my header. I do this with `get_term_link($term->slug, 'my_taxonomy')`;

In my new function for the breadcrumbs I'd like to query if I'm on one of this pages and print this term.

First off, … I'm doing this …

```
if ( is_taxonomy_hierarchical('my_taxonomy) ) {
            echo "test";
```

But now my function is depending on this `my_taxonomy` string. I'd love to work this function for all upcoming taxonomies. How can I do this? There are conditional tags like `is_category()` that doesn't need any params. Why do all term- or taxonomy-conditionals need this param?

And how can I print the current-term i'm in. Right now I'm just echoing "test" up there, however I'd like to print the current term.

Any ideas on that? Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

```
function list_breadcrumbs() {

    $q_object = get_queried_object();
    $taxonomy = $q_object->taxonomy;

    $seperator = " <span class='separator'>&rang;</span> ";

    if ( !is_home() ) {

            echo "<a href='" . get_bloginfo('url') . "' title='Home'>Home</a>" . $seperator;

        if ( is_category() ) {
            $category = get_the_category(); 
            echo "<span class='breadcrumb'>" . $category[0]->cat_name . "</span>";
        } else if ( is_tax( $taxonomy ) ) {
            echo "The Term Name";
        } else if ( is_single() ) {
            …
        } else if ( is_page() ) {
            …
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want [`get_queried_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object). This is a very generic function - and simply returns the queried object- so a single post, this would be a post object.

For instance, the return object may be of the form:

```
Object (
    [term_id] => 299
    [name] => test
    [slug] => test
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 317
    [taxonomy] => event-category
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 2
)
```

So for instance:

```
  $q_object = get_queried_object();
  if( isset($q_object->taxonomy) ){
     $taxonomy = $q_object->taxonomy;
  }else{
    //Not a taxonomy page
  }
```

To use this in a function:

```
function wpse51753_breadcrumbs(){
    if( !is_tax() && !is_tag() && !is_category() )
       return;

    //If we got this far we are on a taxonomy-term page
    // (or a tag-term or category-term page)
    $taxonomy = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $term_id =  (int) $queried_object->term_id;

    //Echo breadcrumbs
}
```

Then just `wpse51753_breadcrumbs();` in your template wherever you want to display the breadcrumbs.

Comment: Thank you! I updated my question above in order for you to see my current code. The problem with this is that if I'm not on a tax/term page I get this error `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$taxonomy in … functions.php` - So as you see in my sample above, I simply want to have a conditional for my term-page. "If on termpage -> print the term"  

Any ideas?

Comment: That's because the `taxonomy` property won't be set if the queried object isn't a term. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, but in this case do I have to wrap my entire breadcrumbs function inside of this `isset-condition`? I don't get how I could most efficiently apply those lines to my code above. Would you mind showing me this depending on my sample code above. Thank you in advance for your awesome help.

Comment: awesome help added ::). I've used some functions rather than interacting with the queried object directly.

Comment: Any tips for when querying multple categories at a time, like at this URL: `example.com/category/cars+bikes/`?